# How to manage App state

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Say I have designed the Page navigation in this manner :

P(1) -> goto P(2) -> goto P(3)  and at P(3) , the user click the Home button (the Microsoft button)

a) How do I get back to p(3) when the App re-launch ?

Thanks

--- Update

What I need to do on this event ?

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
            // just ensure that the window is active

            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page

                rootFrame = new Frame();

                if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                }

                // Place the frame in the current Window

                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;

            }

            if (rootFrame.Content == null)
            {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter

                if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
                {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
                }
            }

            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use local settings to store the last page opened in `OnNavigatedTo` event of each page.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastPage"] = this.GetType().ToString();
}
```

After than in `OnLaunched(..)` event of App.xaml.cs, you check which was the last page opened. According to that you can navigate it.

```csharp
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
        // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
        // parameter

        if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastPage"] != null)
        {
            Type t = Type.GetType((string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastPage"]);
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(t, args.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }
    }
    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: If I goto P(2) and press the Home button and relaunch, it will display p(2) and not MainPage? It should goto P(3), if I stop at P(3). What I need to do?

Comment: I am not getting what you are talking about. What do you exactly mean by Home button ?

Comment: Sorry. The Home button ( Microsoft or center button)  on the Simulator. When app is running, pressing it will bring to Home screen.

Comment: See the `OnLaunched` will be called only when app is closed or suspended, so it will hard to navigate the app when it's NOT suspended because at that time that last page will be in opened state & in that page [CoreWindow.Activated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.activated(v=win.10).aspx) will be fired so you may use that.

Comment: Sorry, my previous question on Center-button case did not included your updated code. Now,I followed what you did, I got error at this:  if (!rootFrame.Navigate(t, args.Arguments))   where t is null and I have included this line at OnNavigated To event :Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastPage"] = this.GetType().ToString();

Comment: Check what's the value of `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["LastPage"]` ?